# Reference counting problem with Perl 5.12.3?

Tags: perl, lexical-scope

It seems that it's cleaning up the pad too early:

```
sub search { 
    my ( $self, $test ) = @_;
    my $where;
    my $found   = 0;
    my $counter = 0;

    $self->descend( pre_each => sub {
        my $lvl = shift;
        my $ev_return 
            = $lvl->each_value( sub {
               $counter++;
            my ( $name, $value ) = @_;
            say "\$name=$name";
            say "\$value=$value";
            return 1 unless $found = $test->( $value );
            $where = { key => $lvl, name => $name, value => $value };
            # when any intermediate function sees QUIT_FLAG, it 
            # knows to return control to the method that called it.
            return QUIT_FLAG; 
        });
        say "\$found=$found";
        say "\$where=$where";
        return $ev_return;      
    });
    say "\$counter=$counter";
    say "\$found=$found";
    say "\$where=$where";
    return unless $found;
    return $where;
}
```

And what I get is:

```
...
$found=1
$where=HASH(...)
$counter=0
$found=0
$where=
```

Or, if anybody can point to something bone-headed I'm doing, I'd really appreciate it. I even created incremental variables between the first and outer closure, but they got reset too. Even setting *references* on the innermost closure, gets me nothing in the named sub scope!

The entire code concerned here is 500 lines. It is impractical to include the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaning up the pad"?  What outputs were you expecting to get?  What, exactly, do the `descend` and `each_value` methods do?

Comment: @Jack Maney, when I print out the values in the intermediate loop, `$found` is `1` and `$where` is a hash. When I print the values in search, they are both reset to their original value, as if they were localized package variables (which they are not). So I set them in the inner closure, they retain the values in the middle, but they are completely set back to their original value in `search`.

Comment: Axeman: the perl documentation has warned against that kind of conditional initialization for many years now - see "Here be dragons." in perlsyn.  Basically, you are bypassing the runtime effects of the `my`, and that often isn't what you want (and is subject to change in a future perl version).

Comment: As far as actions at a distance go, I would guess you just have straightforward logic errors resulting from the `my ... if ` not doing what you intended.  But it's impossible to say without a self-contained example to try.

Comment: @ysth, Yeah, that makes sense now, normally hanging a conditional suffix off the end of the statement keeps any part of the statement from running, and it makes sense that it would do that with a my. I think the failure is that `strict` does not complain, since--you're kinda not declaring a variable. So let me get this straight: it bypasses `strict` and becomes a *package* variable?

Comment: No.  my has a compile time effect (use of that variable name from the following statement to the end of scope or another my/our for the same name use the lexical) that always happens and a runtime effect (the variable is scheduled to be reset when the scope is left).  You are only (sometimes) suppressing the runtime effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be really good if you could provide a complete, runnable example.

Stab in the dark: does it help to have an extraneous use of $found in the outer anonymous sub (e.g. `$found if 0;`)?

Comment: I've tried everything, including a new lexical scope consisting of a setter and getter;

Comment: I have to give this to you because you pointed out the my with modifiers problem. But people should see my post for an accounting of what was the deal. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Do not use `my` with statement modifiers!

The problem turned out to be in a called scope. Having forgotten the warning against using `my` with a statement modifier, I had coded the following:

```
my $each   = shift if @_ == 1;
my %params = @_ unless $each;
```

The first time it went through `@_` had one argument. It assigned the first value to `$each`. The second time through, with more arguments it *skipped* the `my`. So there was no declaration in the current scope, so it simply reused the sub that I had assigned the last time, and saved nothing in `%params` because the `$each` it referred to *had* a value.

Weird, but as ysth pointed out [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlsyn.html#Statement-Modifiers) warns against this behavior. I think I used to know this, but have forgotten it over the years. Switching it to

```
my ( %params, $each );
if ( @_ == 1 ) { 
    $each = shift;
}
else { 
    %params = @_;
}
```

did the trick. It not only cleaned up the problems I was having with another method, but it cleaned up problems in `search`.